# How to take a Drop Down Value and use it to Find specific Info in tables on other sheets VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to understand how to use a text box value and implement it into a function to locate specific information in a table. I currently have a user input text box as seen in [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T7RI.png). When the user clicks save, I have the information from the text boxes populate a table in sheet 2, by getting the txtdepth.Value. After this point, I am not understanding how to use the same value to locate information in a table in Sheet3... What I am trying currently is to make a function  where the parameter will be the value received from the text cell and do a Vlookup on the value to retrieve the other useful info.

```
Function Depth_Reduct(TargetDepth As Integer)

Dim Depth As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet3")

    Depth = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TargetDepth, Range("AE6:AF16"), 2, True)



End With


End Function
```

I am not sure if I'm going in the right direction. I currently have an excel spreadsheet that meets all my requirements, just transferring the methods into VBA is throwing me off.

Comment: Firstly, you are not using your With block reference. `Range("AE6:AF16")` refers to a range on the `ActiveSheet`, which may or may not be `Sheet3`.  Change that to `.Range("AE6:AF16")` - note the leading `.`

Comment: Secondly, `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` will throw a Runtime error if `TargetDepth` is not found.  Typically you'd wrap that in `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0`, then test Depth for a valid value.

Comment: Thirdly, you are not returning anything from your Function.  Add `Depth_Reduct = Depth` (after suitable testing of the lookup result)

Comment: Thank you @chrisneilsen I was unaware of the Runtime error that will occur, I will give this a shot!